# SAS Visual Analytics Report export detailed data not possible

Tags: sas, sas-visual-analytics

After having updated an Visual Analytics report, the option to **export "Detailed data"** is not available anymore.
Only the export of "Formatted data" is possible.
For other reports, which I did not change, the functionality is still there.

I did undo my changes by reverting to an older version of the SAS meta data, but still the export is not available.

Is there any option to enable that exporting functionality report or table wise?

Comment: I just rebuilt the report and it now works. But still got no clue why it did not work beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

If you removed/renamed variables in your dataset, but not in VA, VA won't be able to export these variables. Thus make sure the metadata in your report are equal to the metadata in your dataset.

That said, you could use this feature if you need detailed data for calculations in your report, but don't want your customers to get hold on all the details. However, as far as I know, this is not a documented feature, so don't rely too much on it, as it may change in the future.